# python find connected components in a 3D graph / tuple with three elements?

Tags: python, graph, connected-components

I have a binary 3D numpy array, for which I would like to find connected components, i.d. neighbor elements with value 1.

```
data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.4, 1000)
data = data.reshape((10,10,10))
```

Alternatively I can get the coordinates for each element with value one and get a set of lists with three elements for which I could get neighboring clusters

```
coordinates = np.argwhere(data > 0)

connected_elements = []
for node in coordinates:
  neighbors = #Get possible neighbors of node
  if neighbors not in connected_elements:
    connected_elements.append(node)
  else:
    connected_elements.index(neighbor).extend(node)
```

How can I do this, or implement a 2D connected_components function for a 3D setting?

Comment: Are you allowed to move only along the axis to find connected components or are we allowed to more across also

Answer (score 3):

Like suggested in the question, we first generate the data and find the coordinates.

Then we can use k-d tree [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) to find neighbours within a distance of 1 with [`query_pairs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs) and use them as edges of the graph, which essentially reduces the problem to a standard graph connected component search.

Then we create the networkx graph from these edges with [`from_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_edgelist.html) and run [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components) to find connected components.

And the last step is visualization.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.ckdtree import cKDTree
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# create data
data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.1, 1000)
data = data.reshape((10,10,10))

# find coordinates
cs = np.argwhere(data > 0)

# build k-d tree
kdt = cKDTree(cs)
edges = kdt.query_pairs(1)

# create graph
G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)

# find connected components
ccs = nx.connected_components(G)
node_component = {v:k for k,vs in enumerate(ccs) for v in vs}

# visualize
df = pd.DataFrame(cs, columns=['x','y','z'])
df['c'] = pd.Series(node_component)

# to include single-node connected components
# df.loc[df['c'].isna(), 'c'] = df.loc[df['c'].isna(), 'c'].isna().cumsum() + df['c'].max()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")
ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], c=df['c'], s=50, cmap=cmhot)
```

Output:

[image]

Notes:

- I've reduced the probability in binomial distribution when generating the nodes from 0.4 to 0.1 to make the visualisation more 'readable'
- I'm not showing connected components that contain only a single node. This can be done with uncommenting the line below the `# to include single-node connected components` comment
- DataFrame `df` contains coordinates `x`, `y` and `z` and the connected component index `c` for each node:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     x  y  z     c
0    0  0  3  20.0
1    0  1  8  21.0
2    0  2  1   6.0
3    0  2  3  22.0
4    0  3  0  23.0
...
```

- Based on the DataFrame `df` we can also check some fun stuff, like the sizes of the biggest connected components found (along with the connected component number):

```
df['c'].value_counts().nlargest(5)
```

Output:

```
4.0    5
1.0    4
7.0    3
8.0    3
5.0    2
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

### DFS to find connected components

```
import queue
import itertools
n = 10

def DFS(data, v, x,y,z, component):
    q = queue.Queue()
    q.put((x,y,z))
    while not q.empty():
        x,y,z = q.get()
        v[x,y,z] = component

        l = [[x], [y], [z]]

        for i in range(3):
            if l[i][0] > 0:
                l[i].append(l[i][0]-1)
            if l[i][0] < v.shape[1]-1:
                l[i].append(l[i][0]+1)

        c = list(itertools.product(l[0], l[1], l[2]))
        for x,y,z in c:
            if v[x,y,z] == 0 and data[x,y,z] == 1:
                q.put((x,y,z))

data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, n*n*n)
data = data.reshape((n,n,n))

coordinates = np.argwhere(data > 0)
v = np.zeros_like(data)

component = 1
for x,y,z in coordinates:
    if v[x,y,z] != 0:
        continue
    DFS(data, v, x,y,z, component)
    component += 1
```

**Main Algo:**

1. Set visited of each point = 0 (denoting that it is not part of any connected
   component yet)
2. for all  points whose value == 1

   3. If the point is not visited  start a DFS starting form it

**DFP:**: It is the traditional DFS algorithm using Queue. The only difference for 3D case is given `(x,y,z)` we calculate all the valid neighbour of it using `itertools.product`. In 3D case every point will have 27 neighbour including itself (3 positions and 3 possible values - same, increment, decrement, so 27 ways).

The matrix `v` stores the connected components numbered starting from 1.

Testcase:

when data =

```
 [[[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]]
```

Visualisation : 
[image]

the two opposite sides are the two different connected components

The algorithm returns v

```
[[[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]]]
```

which is correct.

Visualisation : 
[image]

As can see in the visualisation of `v` green color represent one connected component and blue color represent other connected component.

**Visualization code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            ax.scatter([i]*data.shape[0], [j]*data.shape[1], 
            [i for i in range(data.shape[2])], 
                   c=['r' if i == 0 else 'b' for i in data[i,j]], s=50)

plot(data)
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
plot(v)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume:

1. You are talking about 6 possible neighbors of a node `(i, j, k)` in a 3D graph, and by "neighboring" you mean the distance between the neighbor and the node is 1; and
2. "A valid connected component" means nodeA and nodeB are neighbors and both values are 1.

Then we can have such function to get the possible neighbors:

```
def get_neighbors(data, i, j, k):
    neighbors = []
    candidates = [(i-1, j, k), (i, j-1, k), (i, j, k-1), (i, j, k+1), (i, j+1, k), (i+1, j, k)]
    for candidate in candidates:
        try:
            if data[candidate] == 1:
                neighbors.append(candidate)
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return neighbors
```